# Computing the average of grades in C

Tags: c

I have write a program that allows me to firstly enter a character c followed by an integer n and n float values representing grades. Using array to store the grades I have entered and no more than 100 grades can be introduced. The program allowed me to calculate the sum of the elements in array when I enter 's', compute the production of the elements in array when i enter 'p' and compute the average of the element s when i enter other words. After i enter the grades and character. The program has no response when i hit return to continue. So where is the mistake in my code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int integer_grade [100];
    float floting_grade [100];
    printf("Enter a grade");
    scanf("%i,%f",&integer_grade[100],&floting_grade[100]);
    int *a;
    a=&integer_grade[100];
    int *b;
    b=&floting_grade[100];
    printf("Enter a character");
    getchar();
    scanf("%c",&c);
    int n;
    switch(c)
    {
    case 's':
        for (n=0;n=100;n++)
            *a+=*a;
            *b+=*b;
        printf("Sum is %d",*a+*b);
    case 'p':
        for (n=0;n=100;n++)
            *a*=*a;
            *b*=*b;
        printf("Sum is %d",*a**b);
    default:
        for (n=0;n=100;n++)
            *a+=*a;
            *b+=*b;
        printf("average is %d",(*a+*b)/100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The task is:
Write a program where you first enter a character c followed by an integer n and n float values representing grades. Use an array for storing the grades. You can assume  that not more than 100 grades would be introduced. Yours program should compute and print the following: if c is 's' the sum of the grades, if c is 'p' the product of all grades and if another character was introduced then the arithmetic mean of all grades. 
*use switch 
*you can safely assume thee input will be valid.

Comment: Just a note it is floating_grade not floting_grade you may lose marks.

Comment: C != C++. If you are learning C, don't cross-tag C++ in general unless you are asking for a comparison. The "native" solutions for the different languages might be very different.

Comment: Remove the `c++` tag, this is `C`. Also, why pointers?

Comment: You're only enetering one grade, the one with index 100, which is an invalid index, so your program is undefined. I suggest re-reading the section of your book that introduces arrays. And always use curly braces around your loops.

Comment: also the break-conditions of the for loops are broken (no pun intended). they will run forever since `n=100` is always true.

Comment: From the description of your problem at least take the following steps : first read only one integer `n` (don't need `int integer_grade[100]` array), then run a `for` loop with `n` steps and each step read the floating grade and store it in the array. At the end do your calculations based on user input (some tips how to do it correctly are in answers already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever do you try to do here, it's not right at all.

First: You declare 2 arrays of 100 elements, THEN you assign values outside of that array bounds (100 element array start from 0, finishes at 99)

Second: You create 2 pointers that points to outside of those array bounds.

Third: Inside the switch , the `for (n=0;n=100;n++)` is wrong, it should be something like `for(n = 0; n < 100; n++)`

Fourth: This

```
for (n=0;n=100;n++)
    *a+=*a;
    *b+=*b;
```

it would increment (if that `for` would be correct) only the first statement.
Correct way would be

```
for (n = 0; n < 100; n++)
{
    *a += *a;
    *b += *b;
}
```

Proper code would be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;

    int integer_grade[100];
    float floting_grade[100];

    int nr_of_grades;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter number of grades: ");
    scanf("%d", &nr_of_grades);

    for(i = 0; i < nr_of_grades; i++)

    {
        printf("Enter a int grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer_grade[i]);

    printf("Enter a float grade: ");
    scanf("%f", &floting_grade[i]);
    }


    int operation_i = 0;
    float operation_f = 0;


    printf("Enter a character");
    scanf(" %c", &c);

    int n;

    switch(c)
    {
    case 's':
        for (n = 0; n < nr_of_grades; n++)
        {
            operation_i += integer_grade[n];
            operation_f += floting_grade[n];
        }

        printf("Sums are Int: %d Float: %f", operation_i, operation_f);
    case 'p':

        operation_i = 1;
        operation_f = 1;


        for (n = 0; n < nr_of_grades; n++)
        {
            operation_i *= integer_grade[n];
            operation_f *= floting_grade[n];
        }

        printf("Products are Int: %d Float: %f", operation_i, operation_f);

    default:
        for (n = 0; n < nr_of_grades; n++)
        {
            operation_i += integer_grade[n];
            operation_f += floting_grade[n];
        }

        printf("Average is Int: %d Float: %f", operation_i / nr_of_grades, operation_f / nr_of_grades);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. That is result I want to get. I think I may not understand the question clearly.

Comment: @UniCell maybe you should get the mark for doing his homework.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch yes, i know, that's my fault. I did it just because after seeing the horror he wrote i couldn't believe he would do something proper. I took pity on him and i accept my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Thoughts.

1. This is undefined behavior. You are assigning the read integer and float to offset 100 in those arrays, which doesn't exist.

   ```
   int integer_grade[100];
   float floting_grade[100];
   scanf("%i,%f", &integer_grade[100], &floting_grade[100]);
   ```
2. These pointers point to memory that is outside the bounds of their respective arrays.

   ```
   int *a = &integer_grade[100];
   int *b = &floting_grade[100];
   ```
3. You ask for a character and then you ignore the value of that character:

   ```
   getchar();
   ```

   You then follow that up by getting the following character. Which is odd. But you do use the correct type and what not. So that's a win.

   ```
   scanf("%c",&c);
   ```
4. Your indentation in these for loops implies that you think that both statements will be iterated on as part of the loop. That's incorrect. Use `{ ... }` to accomplish that:

   ```
   for (n=0;n=100;n++)
       *a+=*a;
       *b+=*b;
   ```
5. I have no idea what you think you're accomplishing by `*a += *a`. I do know that the value at `*a` is going to grow quite quickly (and will likely overflow).
6. Switch statements use fallthrough on the cases. That means that if your case is `'s'`, it will run all of the code in the switch statement, including all three cases. If you don't want this behavior, you should place break statements at the end of each case.
7. Please go back to your book / faculty / internet resource and read how a for loop works. This doesn't do what you probably think it does. In fact, this is an infinite loop!

   ```
   for (n=0; n=100; n++)
   ```

Comment: 7. the loop conditional is an assignment

Comment: I believe the `getchar` is meant to skip the newline from the previous input. But it's better to write `scanf(" %c", &c)`.

Comment: 5. is wrong, it doubles the value each iteration, so the result would be `*a *= 1<<100;`, which is way too large for an int.

Comment: @mch: One of them uses multiplication, one uses addition. I'm talking about the addition version. But either way, the for loop doesn't iterate 100 times. It iterates inf times.

Comment: me too. the addition version doubles each iteration and so it will overflow at the 31nd iteration (starting with 1). the multiplication version squares its value each iteration and will overflow at the 5th iteration (starting with 2). `*a*= 100;` would be if the added value don't increase, but that is not the case here.